# When using MySQL request in foreach, first select is good, but then not

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

With this code:

```
foreach ($content as $value) {
    $data=$value[0];
    echo $data; 
    $req="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE data='$data'";
    $result=mysql_query($req) or die ('Erreur :'.mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)){
        echo '  ENTRY EXISTS';
    }
    else {
        echo '  ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST';
    }   
}
```

For the first `$value` it finds an entry, which is correct. For the next ones it doesn't, but it should. How can this be fixed?

---

**Update code**

With this code:

```
        $found_list = array();

        $fetch_list = array();
        foreach($content as $value){
            $fetch_list[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value[0]) . "'";
        }

        if( empty($fetch_list) ){
            echo '<p>No data to fetch</p>';
        }else{

            $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT inst_name
                FROM INSTITUTS
                WHERE inst_name IN (' . implode(', ', $fetch_list) . ')';
            $res = mysql_query($sql)
                or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ){
                $found_list[] = $row['inst_name'];
            }
            var_dump($found_list);
        }

        foreach($content as $value){
            echo '<br/>';
            echo $value[0] . ' ';
            if( in_array($value[0], $found_list) ){
                echo "ENTRY EXISTS\n <br/>";
            }else{
                echo "ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST\n <br/>";
            }
        }
```

And the result is :

```
 array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "AixEnProvence" [1]=> string(19) "AixEnProvenceAnnexe" [2]=> string(7) "Acheres" } 
acheres ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST 
AixEnProvence ENTRY EXISTS 
aixenprovenceannexe ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST 
instituttest ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST
```

Comment: please post the var_dump of $content before the loop!

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => acheres [1] => Mars [2] => 6 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => Bienv 15/03 [6] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => AixEnProvence [1] => Avril [2] => 6 [3] => 0 [4] => 35 [5] => Bienv 15/03 [6] => ) [2] => Array ( [0] => aixenprovenceannexe [1] => Mai [2] => 6 [3] => 0 [4] => 19 [5] => Bienv 15/03 [6] => ) [3] => Array ( [0] => instituttest [1] => Juin [2] => 6 [3] => 0 [4] => 17 [5] => Bienv 15/03 [6] => ) )

Comment: Does echo $data result in:

acheres, AixEnProvence, aixenprovenceannexe and instututtest?

Comment: Please also post here content of the TABLE, from which we read info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason to flood the MySQL server with almost identical queries. Have a look at the [`IN` expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/expressions.html):

```
SELECT foo, bar
FROM table
WHERE data IN ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

I also suggest you google for SQL Injection and XSS attacks.

**Edit:** Here's some code that solves the problem as described in latest comments:

```
<?php

// $content = ...
$found_list = array();

$fetch_list = array();
foreach($content as $value){
    $fetch_list[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value[0]) . "'";
}

if( empty($fetch_list) ){
    echo '<p>No data to fetch</p>';
}else{
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT data
        FROM table
        WHERE data IN (' . implode(', ', $fetch_list) . ')';
    $res = mysql_query($sql)
        or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ){
        $found_list[] = $row['data'];
    }
}

foreach($content as $value){
    echo $value[0] . ' ';
    if( in_array($value[0], $found_list) ){
        echo "ENTRY EXISTS\n";
    }else{
        echo "ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST\n";
    }
}

?>
```

**Answer to updated question:**

PHP [comparison operators](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) are case sensitive:

```
<?php
var_dump('Acheres'=='acheres'); // bool(false)
?>
```

You can use [strtolower()](http://php.net/strtolower) to normalize values before comparing.

Comment: This is a local based application. After the test will come a new request. I dont quite understand how i can use the IN expression in my case.

Comment: @Clément: I've updated my answer. BTW, the *localness* of an application does not change the SQL or HTML syntaxes ;-)

Comment: @Alvaro, Thank for your help, but as a beginner i don't really get what we are doing now. The sql function will check if entries are in the database, but what kind of $result is this?

Comment: I will need to echo something for each unavailable entry too.

Comment: @Clément: Hmmm... Do you mean that you are currently doing `SELECT *` just to *count* the returned rows and see whether it's zero or not? Don't you *need* the returned data itself?

Comment: I dont need the returned data, i just need to list which entries are in it, and which are isnt. Im goin to echo somehting for each one.

Comment: @Alvaro-g-vicario Thanks for your help. I've tried the code but every single entry echo a "ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST". it does echo the name of value[0] tho.

Comment: Array ( [0] => 'acheres' [1] => '\rAixEnProvence' [2] => '\raixenprovenceannexe' [3] => '\rinstituttest' ) is the result of print_r of fetch_list.

Comment: @Clément, I suggest you use `var_dump()`. The output of `print_r()` is nicer but it can hide important details. Whatever, does you data really start with literal `\r` characters?

Comment: This is ,y final result: array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "'acheres'" [1]=> string(15) "'AixEnProvence'" [2]=> string(21) "'aixenprovenceannexe'" [3]=> string(14) "'instituttest'" } acheres ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST AixEnProvence ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST aixenprovenceannexe ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST instituttest ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST

Comment: @Clément: you say nothing about `$found_list` or your sample data. Do items exist on DB? And, are they found by the query?

Comment: @Alvaro-g-vicario Yes items are in the database, how can i verify if they are found by the query?

Comment: @Clément: Just `var_dump($found_list)` the same way you did with `$fetch_list`. Do you *understand* the code?

Comment: @Alvaro-g-vicario I forgot to change a variable name but now its ok. this is the var_dump($found_list) + final result array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "AixEnProvence" [1]=> string(19) "AixEnProvenceAnnexe" [2]=> string(7) "Acheres" } acheres ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST AixEnProvence ENTRY EXISTS aixenprovenceannexe ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST instituttest ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST

Comment: @Alvaro-g-vicario I still do not understand why i got the "ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST" when it does

Comment: @Clément: neither do I. Code and dumps in comments are unreadable. If you have further questions, feel free to edit the original question and provide full details.